# How to change the primary key of manytomany table in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, primary-key, django-1.11

I am changing the primary key of the legacy database. I was able to change the primary key by setting id as the primary key.

Before

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

After

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This is working fine.
But I also want to change the default primary key of the tables created via ManyToMany feild.

User Model

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

UserProfile Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

The ManytoMany field creates table called User_user_userprofile with id as Autofield basically previous or default django primary key.

id, user_id, userprofile_id
[ManytoMany Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDbHm.png)

Now, How to change the primarykey of ManytoMany Feild ie id created by Django?

PS:
Django: 1.11
Python: 2.7.5
DB: Sqlite3 3.7.17 2013-05-20

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem today, and ended up solving it by using the `through` argument of the `ManyToManyField`. I solved it for Django v3.2.6 however, but the documentation for v1.11 mentions the same behavior for the same argument, so hopefully the solution should work for your version of Django too. Here's the link to the documentation for v1.11 [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

What the `through` argument allows you to do is to create the intermediary table (created automatically by `ManyToManyField`) yourself. You get finer control of how the intermediary table should look like, what fields it should have and what their behavior should be. Hope you are getting a picture.

Let me give you the example of the problem I faced and how I solved it. Hopefully that will make this clearer.

I was trying to establish a many-to-many relationship between two of my existing models.

My first model looks like this,

```py
class BanglaWords(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bangla Words'

    bng_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    bangla_word = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bangla_word
```

and the second one looks like,

```py
class EnglishWords(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'English Words'

    eng_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bangla_word = models.ManyToManyField(BanglaWords)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

But this resulted in an intermediary table `wordnet_englishwords_bangla_word` which looked like this,

| wordnet_englishwords_bangla_word |
| --- |
| id |
| englishwords_id |
| banglawords_id |

But I didn't want this, I wanted `bng_id` to be the `pk` for this table. I solved the problem with `ManyToManyField.through` as follows,

I defined the intermediary model(table) myself and with the `through` argument, I pointed to the new intermediary model I created and instructed django to create the table the way I wanted it.

First I created the intermediary model,

```py
class BanglaEnglishRelations(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bangla English Relations'

    bng_id = models.OneToOneField('BanglaWords', primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    eng_id = models.ForeignKey('EnglishWords', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

which defines `bng_id` as the primary key as I desired.

Second, I told the `ManyToManyField` in `EnglishWords` to base the table on `BanglaEnglishRelations` like,

```py
bangla_word = models.ManyToManyField(BanglaWords, through=BanglaEnglishRelations)
```

This resulted in the table `wordnet_banglaenglishrelations` which looked like,

| wordnet_banglaenglishrelations |
| --- |
| bng_id_id |
| eng_id_id |

and surved my purposes. You can do something similar to solve your problem and promote whatever field to a `pk`.